# Let fs works at build time (webpack)

Tags: node.js, webpack, build, swagger, openapi

I have a simple node app built in Koa and I have this function in `app.ts`

```
export const generateSwagger = async (spec: OpenAPIParam): Promise<void> => {
  await fs.promises.rm(__dirname + '/../dist', {
    recursive: true,
    force: true,
  });
  await fs.promises.mkdir(__dirname + '/../dist');
  await fs.promises.mkdir(__dirname + '/../dist/doc');
  await fs.promises.writeFile(
    __dirname + '/../dist/doc/swagger.json',
    JSON.stringify(spec),
    'utf8',
  );
};
```

This function is called only at build time.
It worked until a month ago, when webpack finished I had

```
dist/
  |--- index.js
  |--- doc/
        |--- swagger.json
```

I don't know why now the `fs` function isn't working anymore, I don't have any errors.
I can't use an external script cause I only have the specs inside the code